# using getchar() and getting stuck in loop

Tags: c++

I'm getting stuck in infinite while loop while trying to use getchar() to read characters from an input file.  What am I doing wrong? Would another function work better?

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <fstream>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <stdio.h>

 using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  ifstream in;
  char C;
  string filename;

   if(argc == 1)
   {
     cout << "Not enough arguments"<<endl;
     exit(1);
   }
   while(1)
     {
        C = in.getchar();
        if(C ==EOF)
          break;
      }
```

Comment: For one, `c` will never be `EOF`.  Infinite loop.

Comment: `getchar` reads from `stdin`, maybe you want `inFile.get()` ?

Comment: getchar() reads character from stdin, not from file you open

Comment: Thank you.  I'll try get().

Comment: @Eljay Why? It will be EOF, if one entered EOF character into stdin.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius • `getchar` returns an int, which may be an `EOF`.  `EOF` is not a character.  `c` is a char.  `EOF` won't "fit" in `c`.

Comment: @Eljay `EOF` "_expands to an integer constant expression, with type `int` and a negative value_" (note: no exact value of `EOF` is given), and "_If the destination type is signed, the value is unchanged if it can be represented in the destination type; otherwise, the value is implementation-defined._". So, if the value of `EOF`, on OPs compiler (i.e. the standard library that compiler uses), can be represented with `char`, `c` can, very well, be equal to `EOF`.